# Why do Pi and E have different precision in java.lang.Math?

Tags: java, math

In java.lang.Math, we can see two constants:

public static final double E = 2.7182818284590452354;

public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

I'm curious why pi is accurate to 20 decimal places, and E to 19.

Comment: doubles are not accurate to _any_ decimal places; they're accurate to binary places.

Comment: Neither one is as accurate as it seems. Try writing a program in which you assign these constants to a double variable and then print them out.

Comment: It's still curious that they were specified to different decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's irrelevant since the `Math.E` version can't hold the precision specifed in the library.  The `trunc` version is missing the next 4 digits but the IEEE754 bits are identical to both.

```
long elib = Double.doubleToLongBits(2.7182818284590452354);
String elibbits =Long.toBinaryString(elib);
long etrunc = Double.doubleToLongBits(2.718281828459045);
String etruncbits = Long.toBinaryString(etrunc);
System.out.println(elibbits);
System.out.println(etruncbits);
System.out.println(elibbits.equals(etruncbits));
```

prints

```
100000000000101101111110000101010001011000101000101011101101001
100000000000101101111110000101010001011000101000101011101101001
true
```

Perhaps the author knew that beyond a certain number of decimal places that extraneous digits would be ignored.

Here is the linke to the [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) Wiki page.  The table says that `64` bits can hold a maximum of `15.95` digits.

Comment: Thanks, according to this, it seems both PI and E has redundant precision here.

Comment: @VicSun I would tend to agree with that.

Comment: WJS - I'm sure that the author knew that.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Vic Sun's great answer, a *declaration* for a `double` is not the same thing as the *internal representation* of that `double`.

The compiler will allow you to put many digits (at leaset 100) after the decimal place. If that *declared* number exceeds what the internal representation *allows*, the additional digits will be discarded.

Here's an example of a `double` declaration with 40 digits in the decimal part, with every "0" at a multiple of 10 for easy counting. The internal representation of `double` is 16 digits of decimal accuracy. Even though the declaration (40 digits) exceeds the storable accuracy (16), the code is still valid and the compiler is fine with it.

```
final double x = 1.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890;
//                          ^- 10     ^- 20     ^- 30     ^- 40
System.out.println("x: " + x);
```

Here's the output from running that, showing that the 16th decimal place (which should have been a "6") was instead rounded from "6" up to "7", and everything after that (position 17 through 40) was truncated:

```
x: 1.1234567890123457
```

This can also be seen when stepping through with a debugger: the value of `x` is similarly shown to hold the value "1.1234567890123457" – again, 16 digits of decimal accuracy.

We could define a `double` with 100 digits of accuracy for *pi*:

```
final double piTo100Digits = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679;
System.out.println(piTo100Digits);
```

But at runtime we will end up with the same truncation (this time, to 15 digits instead of 16):

```
3.141592653589793
```

So the original question – *why are the constants defined with different lengths?* – is definitely not about actual numeric accuracy. They're both longer than 16 digits (`E` is defined with 19 digits accuracy, `PI` with 20 digits) and both will be truncated. They're copied below from `java.lang.Math` in OpenJDK 17:

```
public static final double E  = 2.7182818284590452354;
public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
```

Just to be sure, we can print them out from running code:

```
System.out.println("Math.E  : " + Math.E);
System.out.println("Math.PI : " + Math.PI);
```

This confirms both values are truncated to 15 digits at runtime:

```
Math.E  : 2.718281828459045
Math.PI : 3.141592653589793
```

Also, just because I was curious, both `E` and `PI` are [listed in Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Math.PI) with 15-digit accuracy, and not the 19 or 20-digit long values that appear in code:

```
java.lang.Math
Modifier and Type           Constant  Field Value
public static final double  E         2.718281828459045
public static final double  PI        3.141592653589793
```